# Invisible reCAPTCHA error SCRIPT5005 in IE 11

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

We are having problems with recaptca v2 (invisible) in our website using IE11.
It appears to be an error inside recaptcha itself, because we did not launch any new version recently.

We can not public inform our site, so I´ll try to explain exactly what is happening.

After open the page for the first time, it works.

[on open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BusFD.png)

But if we refresh the page just one time (F5), the error appears in the console log (F12).

SCRIPT5005: Cadeia esperada

recaptcha__pt_br.js (11,465)

SCRIPT5005: Cadeia esperada

recaptcha__pt_br.js (2,137)

[after F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjNs9.png)

If we click in "SCRIPT5005", the following page opens (it´s in portuguese, I could not find a english version)
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/86wk0127(v=vs.94)

We already tried to change every configuration on IE (compatibility view, reset browser to default, security zones), but the result is always the same.

No problem with browsers:

Chrome - 76.0.3809.132 - 64 bits

Firefox - 68.0.2 - 64 bits

Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0

Could anyone help ?

References

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

https://support.google.com/recaptcha/?hl=en-GB#6223838